# Regex to match string excluding first character

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

I'm writing ruby and need some help with regex. And I'm really noob in regexp. 
I have a string like this

```
/hello/world
```

I would like to #gsub this string to change **the second** slash to %2F. 
The challange for me to ignore the first slash and to change **only the second** slash.
I tried this one

```
[^/]/
```

but it chooses not clean slash but **o/** in

```
/hello/world
```

Please, help me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply capture the character before the slash in a group and use that in the replacement, for example:

```
"/hello/world".gsub(/([^\/])\//, '\1%2F') #=> "/hello%2Fworld"
```

Or if you just want to match any `/` that appears after the first character, you can simplify this to:

```
"/hello/world".gsub(/(.)\//, '\1%2F')     #=> "/hello%2Fworld"
```

Or like this:

```
"/hello/world".gsub(/(?<!^)\//, '%2F')    #=> "/hello%2Fworld"
```

Comment: While we're at it, `"/hello%2Fwolrd".sub('lr', 'rl')`.  Since you're using `\1`, may as well use `sub`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Woops made a typo while testing. Thanks

Comment: I like the last one! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

And now for an uglier, regexless alternative:

```
"/hello/world".split("/").tap(&:shift).unshift("/").join("")
```

I'll see myself out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subpattern within `()` for find substring:

```
/^\/(.*)$/
```

or

```
/^.(.*)$/
```

this pattern excluding first character. And then replace `/` in this substring

Answer (score 1):

`(?!^\/)\/`

http://rubular.com/r/IRWptAJdLs is a a working example.

Comment: ^ This is the correct answer. "/hello/world".sub(/(?!^\/)\//, '') == "/helloworld"

Comment: Tsk! Tsk! You're suggesting the use of a negative lookahead to a self-admitted "regex noob", with NO EXPLANATION!

Answer (score 0):

change the second `/` to `%2F`:

```
'/hello/world'.sub /(\/.*?)\//, '\1%2F'
#=> "/hello%2Fworld"
```